# im trying to count returned documents in mongodb with facet and got issue

Tags: mongodb

im trying to count the results with $facet and when im adding count its counting but not showing the $project results, if I remove the count then i see the results, im new to mongoDb and still learning , any help will be apprecieted , thanks
the code im using right now

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      documents: [
        {
          "$match": {
            "dstChannel": "",
            "destination": "960",
            "date": {
              "$gte": "2022-01-20 21:43:13",
              "$lte": "2022-01-25 23:43:14"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$project": {
            "destination": 1,
            "source": 1,
            "date": 1,
            "duration": 1
          }
        },
         {
            $count: "documents"
          }
        
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/B2XioF-bytb)

Comment: Is [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tcLDu33XO5Y) what are you looking for? (or [this one](https://mongoplayground.net/p/woQ1Bav1_Az))

Comment: the second one is the right one :) ,thanks s lot

Comment: J.F post the result so i mark it as solved , thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To count the documents you can use `$size` after the `$facet` stage.

The main problem in your query is you want to access the `documents` field into the `$facet` but the documents are available after `$facet` is completed.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      documents: [
        {
          "$match": {
            "dstChannel": "",
            "destination": "960",
            "date": {
              "$gte": "2022-01-20 21:43:13",
              "$lte": "2022-01-25 23:43:14"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$project": {
            "destination": 1,
            "source": 1,
            "date": 1,
            "duration": 1
          }
        }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "$addFields": {
        "nDocuments": {
          "$size": "$documents"
        }
      }
    }
  ])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/woQ1Bav1_Az)